# how can i create an objects property from variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i want to do something like this,

```
function MyObject(args){
    keys=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(args)
    keys.forEach(function(key){
        this[key]=args[key]             
    })
}
```

after this i tried creating an object, but it's attributes were not set..

```
n=new MyObject({title:'x',age:19})
console.log(n.title)
```

OutPut:undefined!!

so can anyone tell me what im doing wrong...i even tried replaced `this[key]` with `MyObject[key]`, but got same result..

Comment: Use an arrow function instead, else your `this` will refer to the wrong object

Comment: thanks, it worked,sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the forEach, the value of `this` is not the instance of `MyObject` that you are creating. You could use an arrow function, or you could store the `this` you want in the upper scope:

```js
function MyObject(args){
    var self = this;
    keys=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(args)
    keys.forEach(function(key){
        self[key]=args[key]             
    })
}

n=new MyObject({title:'x',age:19})

console.dir(n)
console.log(n.title)
```

```js
function MyObject(args){
    keys=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(args)
    keys.forEach((key) => {
        this[key]=args[key]             
    })
}

n=new MyObject({title:'x',age:19})

console.dir(n)
console.log(n.title)
```

Comment: maybe you should add an example with an arrow function